# Routing Pattern Matched not getting called from multiple Routes

Tags: routes, sapui5

I am trying to call View (SR_CreateRequestDetail.view) from mulitple source Views. On Route Pattern Matched event, I have to check the parameter name `oEvent.getParameter("name")` to identify from which view, it is getting called.

it is only working for `SR_CreateRequestDetail` route. If i am using different routes targeting this view, Target pattern matching is not getting called when control is moving from source to target.

I also tried to call `onInit` `getRoute` without any route and check that in `_onRoutePatternMatched`. But this generic call is not working.

**Source Controller:**

```
onAddBusinessCase: function (oEvent) {
           this.oRouter.navTo("SR_CreateRequestDetail", {
                         header: JSON.stringify(Header)
                       });
```

**Target Controller:**

```
onInit: function () {

        // this.oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        this.oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
        this.oRouter.getRoute("SR_CreateRequestDetail").attachPatternMatched(this._onRoutePatternMatched, this);

    },

    _onRoutePatternMatched: function (oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getParameter("name") !== "SR_CreateRequestDetail") {
            return;
        }
```

**Manifest.json**

```
"routes": [
            {
                "pattern": "",
                "name": "appHome",
                "target": "Main"
            },
            {
                "name": "SR_CreateRequestDetail",
                "pattern": "SR_CreateRequestDetail/{header}",
                "target": [
                    "SR_CreateRequestDetail"
                ]
            },

"targets": {
            "Main": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "viewPath": "nov.sr.reduction.view",
                "viewId": "idMainPage",
                "viewName": "Main"
            },
            "SR_CreateRequestDetail": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewName": "SR_CreateRequestDetail"
            },
```

Also i am getting below navigation error as soon as calling any navigation.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: I.fFunction.call is not a function
at d.a.fireEvent (sap-ui-core.js:449)
at d.fireRoutePatternMatched (Router.js:6)
at d.fireRoutePatternMatched (Router.js:6)
at constructor.eval (Route.js:6)
```

My Component.js has below code to initialize my router.

```
this.getRouter().initialize();
```

Comment: `I.fFunction.call is not a function` usually means that a callback function does not exist. Does `_onRoutePatternMatched` exist in your code? Do you have more callbacks somewhere else?

Comment: I have added more details to the post. Yes, It has other call backs from different views.

Comment: any luck on this @Marc...

Comment: No, but I don't know your source code so I cannot help. One of your event handlers does not exist. That's all I can guess.

Comment: @Marc - which missing event handler, you are talking about ?